# Getting "undefined is not an object" trying to pass navigator prop to grandchildren

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My React Native app structure is as follows: a Drawer navigator, which contains a BottomTabNavigator, which itself contains 3 tabs (each of them Stack navigators). My issue comes when trying to pass the drawer navigation prop to one of the BottomTabNavigator stacks. I am trying to pass it to a custom component in the headerLeft of one of my Stacks, however I get an "Undefined is not an object" when calling navigation.openDrawer within the headerLeft component.

## App.js

```
<NavigationContainer ref={containerRef} initialState={initialNavigationState}>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{swipeEnabled: false}} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStack} options={{swipeEnabled: false}} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

### BottomTabNavigator.js

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <MyHomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: true,
    headerLeft: (props) => <HamburgerIcon {...props} /> 
   }}>
      <MyHomeStack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen}/>
    </MyHomeStack.Navigator>
  );

{...MessageStack Code}

{...ProfileStack Code}


export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {

return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME} >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStack}
        options={{title: 'Feed'}}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Messages"
        component={MessagesStack}
        options={{title: 'Messages'}}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStack}
        options={{title: 'Profile'}}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

#### HamburgerIcon.js

```
function HamburgerIcon(props) {
    const ({ navigation }) = props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            marginLeft: 10
        }}
        onPress={(navigation) => navigation.openDrawer()} >
            <SafeAreaView style={{alignSelf: "center"}}>
                 <Ionicons name='ios-menu' size={28} color='#000000'/>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
export default HamburgerIcon;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Courtesy of Reddit user ringeril

```
<MyHomeStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    headerLeft: (props) => <HamburgerIcon {...props} /> 
  }
}>
```

headerLeft props does not contain navigation you need to get it from main component.

```
headerLeft: (props) => <HamburgerIcon {...props} navigation={navigation} />
```

Or use the navigation hook.